# Why can't I give constant reference of a pointer as function argument

Tags: c++

Why does c++ not compile the following?

```cpp
void func(const int *&pp) 
{ 
    //Do stuff
} 

int main()
{
    int var =23;
    int* ptr_to_var = &var;
    func(ptr_to_var);
}
```

To clarify I want to pass a pointer as reference to a function, but the pointer should not be changed in the function hence the const.

The compile warning I get is:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const int*&' from expression of type 'int*'
```

I could do something like this:

```cpp
void func(int **pp) 
{ 
    //Do stuff
}
```

But this doesn't give me the exact behavior I would want as now I can actually change the location where the pointer points to, i.e. I miss the const key word.

If you would then do:

```cpp
void func(const int **pp) 
{ 
    //Do stuff
}
```

This doesn't compile either and I'm actually not sure that if it would compile it would actually do what I want.

Comment: What does `func` purport to do?

Comment: you need to show how you call the function. [mcve] please

Comment: in any case the pointer (ie the address) is passed by value when you do func (int *ptr) . There is not risk that func would modify prt and impact the caller. So what is the need for passing the pointer as const reference? There is not performance gain in doing so and it make the function prototype more obscure than what it need to be (imo).

Comment: Your question does not jibe with your code.  Your code should read `void func(int* const& pp)` or `void func(int const* const& pp)`.

Comment: Thanks @Eljay, this actually does what I want. Unfortunately the the question is closed so I kind ask you to put it as answer such that I can accept it.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I was unaware that the function call should be included. I added it in the first example. If you could reopen the question I can give Eljay aswer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Eljays "answer" is just a comment. You cannot accept it. The answer (from eerorika) you have is now out-of-sync because it refers to a question that is now quite different. Thats a reason you should not change the question substantially after you received answers. This case is a bit fishy, because the question should have been improved **before** it got answers. In any case, I think there is no problem in leaving it closed, seems like you know the solution by now, and next time you hopefully know why it is better to include a [mcve].

Comment: btw there is really no point in passing a `const` reference to a pointer. You do that if you want to avoid an expensive copy so that instead only a reference (usually implemented as pointer) is passed, but there is no gain in passing a pointer as const reference

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't agree that there is really no point in passing a const reference to a pointer. You don't know my complete case. In my current case I'm actually interested in the pointer and not in the value stored at the pointer. I could explain you my whole case but I guess that is a bit of a overkill for this question.

Comment: @C.Binair indeed I don't know your case, but I believe there is no such case. If you are interested in the pointer not what it points to then you pass the pointer. Thats no reason to use a reference

Comment: @idclev463035818 I know I can't accept a comment as an answers that why I liked the question to be reopened such that Eljay's comment could be turned into an answer that I can accept. I'm sorry my question at first was incorrect and the given answer is now out of sync. But the given answer is actually not an answer because it just says that my code does compile while I mention it does not.

Comment: @idclev463035818 True about what you say if I'm interested at the pointer and not the value that I could pass the just the pointer and not the reference. But I my case I'm actually interested in a pointer to the pointer. Hence I need the reference, otherwise the location would be wrong.

Comment: @C.Binair an answer can only adress the question as written. I know it is difficult to write a good quesiton, but changing the question to ask a different question when there already is an answer is not nice

Comment: @C.Binair thats actually a case I didn't consider, though still you don't **need** the reference. Acutally I would prefer to pass a `int **` then (possibly cv-qualified) to make it explicit that the function needs the pointer to the pointer not the pointer.

Comment: @C.Binair consider that passing a `const` reference is used to avoid copies, someone seeing a `const int*&` getting passed as parameter might mistakenly think the reference is not needed and refactor it to pass a `int*`. Code not only needs to be correct now, it also needs to be correct in a month, after refactorings and it wont be always you who does that.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does c++ not compile the following?
>
> ```
> void func(const int *&pp) 
> { 
>     //Do stuff
> }
> ```

This is well-formed, and any standard conforming compiler will compile it.

---

> The compile warning I get is:
>
> ```
> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const int*&' from expression of type 'int*'
> ```

The error message isn't very clear, but I think it is trying to say that you tried to initialise the reference with an rvalue. References to non-const lvalues cannot be bound to rvalues.

> If you would then do:
>
> ```
> void func(const int **pp) 
> { 
>     //Do stuff
> }
> ```
>
> This doesn't compile either

This is also well-formed, and a standard conforming compiler must accept it.

You can see both examples succesfully compiling [here](https://godbolt.org/z/L4V2FZ).